# How to reflect classes like java.Math(I would like to extract parameters' types of functions like: Math.abs(), etc.)

Tags: java

I am trying to get the parameters' types(double, int) of the functions like Math.sin(double), Math.abs(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getParameterTypes()` for publicly declared methods. Something like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Method m : Math.class.getMethods()) {
        Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
        for (Class<?> param : params) {
            System.out.println(m.getName()+":"+param.getCanonicalName());
        }
     }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't chage the type of that function bec that are provided by Java and it's final class you can't chage the type

Comment: OP has asked to get parameter types not modifying them